# What does "shown for scale of purchasing power" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, sentence-meaning

On this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millionaire

In the right part, there is a photo of a luxury house. The text underneath says:

> A large suburban home valued at roughly $1,000,000 (2006) in Salinas, California, **shown for scale of purchasing power**

I've read that sentence many times, but I can't figure out what they mean. Do they mean that the photo is shown on the article to demonstrate what a millionaire can afford (but then they would have $0 left...)? Or does it mean that the house itself is "shown for scale of purchasing power", in the sense that the owners are "showing off" by living in it?

I very often find sentences like this which are probably crystal clear to everyone else, but confuse me.

Comment: *A large suburban home valued at roughly $1,000,000 (2006) in Salinas, California, shown for scale of purchasing power* = A large suburban home valued at roughly $1,000,000 (2006) in Salinas, California, shown as an object of comparison in order to show you the purchasing power of $1,000,000 in 2006. -- The fault with the picture is that unless you know how much the house would cost now, it is a meaningless photograph.

Comment: It's a bit of an odd way to put is but I think it means that the picture is there to show you what sort of house you could get for $1,000,000 in Salinas in 2006. This is probably more than you could get for that price in, say, Beverley Hills but less than you could get in, say, Detroit. The point about saying that the picture is there to show scale is that the property is probably not for sale but was a typical $1,000,000 suburban home in Salinas in 2006.

Answer (score 0):

> Scale = a set of numbers, amounts, etc., used to measure or compare the level of something:
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scale)

The reader is invited to compare money with property, and the house is shown as a measure of what could be bought (= the purchasing power) for a million dollars at that time in California.

The set that comprises the scale is small in this case, being only one sum of money and one house. In general, a scale would include more example pairs.

Such scales usefully illustrate purchasing power or the worth of money in different places or times. Other scales might have compared sums of money with cars, areas of land, jewels or other assets. The scale appropriate to money and property in California would not necessarily apply elsewhere.  A million dollars in desirable areas of London might have bought a small apartment or a few square metres of land. In north Scotland it may have bought a mansion or a thousand acres. The scale of purchasing power of 7.2 million today is a modest New York apartment; in 1867 it was sufficient to purchase Alaska.